# MySQL trigger to change products price status to inactive after a new price list become active

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-8.0

I need to create a before update trigger to change the status of "old" product prices' after the new one becomes 'active'

price list table:

```
id  product_id  supplier list_price_uom start_date  price_status
1   101761      ABC         16.26       2021-02-01  Active
2   101761      DEF         19.5        2021-07-01  Active
3   1086        ABC         32.52       2021-02-01  Active
4   1087        ABC         32.52       2021-02-01  Active
5   AWBWHL      ABC         82.23       2021-02-01  Active
6   101761      ABC         19.26       2021-08-30  Scheduled
7   1086        ABC         37.52       2021-08-30  Scheduled
8   1087        ABC         34.52       2021-08-30  Scheduled
9   AWBWHL      ABC         85.23       2021-08-30  Scheduled
```

I have an event that updates the status to 'Active' when start_date = curdate()

```
CREATE EVENT "change_status" 
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY STARTS
'2021-08-26 00:00:00' ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE ENABLE DO UPDATE
price_list_test SET status = 'Active' WHERE status = 'Scheduled' 
AND start_date = curdate()
```

all I need is to change all 'active' rows to 'inactive' when the same SKU (from the same supplier) gets updated by the event.

I have tried different variations of:

```
BEFORE UPDATE ON "price_list_test" FOR EACH ROW  
BEGIN  IF (new.product_id = old.product_id) and (new.supplier = old.supplier) and (old.start_date < CURDATE()) THEN     SET  old.price_status = 'Inactive';
end if ;
END
```

this one gives me the error "updating OLD row is not allowed in trigger:

removing the "old" gives me the error "unknown system variable 'price_status'"

tried this one:

```
BEFORE UPDATE ON "price_list_test" FOR EACH ROW BEGIN 
UPDATE price_list_test  SET  price_status = 'Inactive' where new.product_id = old.product_id and old.start_date < CURDATE()
;
```

which gives me this error
"Error Code: 1442. Can't update table 'price_list_test' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger."

which makes sense and just ran out of ideas.
any help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: A trigger can't update the same table. You'll need to move this logic into the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perform **everything** in the event procedure:

```sql
CREATE EVENT change_status
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY 
            STARTS '2021-08-26 00:00:00' 
ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE 
ENABLE 
DO 
UPDATE    price_list_test t1
LEFT JOIN price_list_test t2 ON t1.SKU = t2.SKU /* replace with correct condition */
                            AND t2.status = 'Active'
SET t1.status = 'Active',
    t2.status = 'Inactive'
WHERE t1.status = 'Scheduled' 
  AND start_date = CURRENT_DATE;
```

None additional operation/code needed in this case.